# Use android shape xml resource on iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml, image

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

I have this resource from an Android app that I did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/gauge_background">

     <gradient
                android:startColor="#449def"
                android:endColor="#2f6699"
                android:angle="270" />

     <stroke
         android:width="1dp"
         android:color="#2f6699" />

     <corners android:radius="30dp" />

     <padding
         android:bottom="10dp"
         android:left="10dp"
         android:right="10dp"
         android:top="10dp" />
</shape>
```

And would like to use it in my iOS app.

**Do you know if there is a way to load this xml and show it as an UIView backgroundColor?**

Something like this:

```
self.backgroundColor =
    [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to do this without converting the original android shape definition to something you can display in a UIView (ie. a nib, or core graphics drawing instructions.)

As far as I am aware no such conversion tool exists.

I'd suggest you look at a tool like [paintcodeapp](http://paintcodeapp.com) to ease the creation of dynamic graphics for your iOS project. (it'll import SVG and turn them into drawing code)

It's very useful for example if you need to anchor / stretch a shape without distorting key parts.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there is no way as @Slomojo said.

If u can, You may convert the xml data in to an `UIImage` and then load that image as `UIcolor`as u mentioned

```
self.backgroundColor =[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
```